# Whitelisting urls in php

Tags: php, url, preg-match

we are developing a chatting application, where students and teachers can communicate via chat communication, now there are assignments in website and if a student has question related to it, he can include the url of that assignment with his message, now we want to whitelist on certain urls for security reasons for both teachers and students.

here how it should work

**message** : question related to this assignment https://school.com/assignment/1425

link is clickable as it is whitelisted

**message** : this assignment has some issue https://schoool.com/assignment/1425

this link has an extra `o` which should be marked as spam in our case, we are going to remove that link

we are unable to find out how we can go about this, I'm mentioning below the desired output we are expecting

`https://school.com` **whitelist**

`https://www.school.com` **whitelist**

`http://school.com` **whitelist**

`http://wwwschool.com` **whitelist**

`school.com` **whitelist**

`www.school.com` **whitelist**

`www.schoool.com` **spam url**

`https://www.schoool.com` **spam url**

`www.schoool.com` **spam url**

`http://www.schoool.com` **spam url**

`schoool.com` **spam url**

**our current code**

```
function filter_url($string = null)
{
    $url = '/(((https?:\/\/)?www)?\.?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\-\/?&#%=]+)/';
    $whitelist = '/\b(school)\b/';
    if(preg_match($url,$string,$output))
    {
        if(preg_match($whitelist,$output[0]))
        {
            // whitelisted string
            return $string;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
     }
 }
```

issue with this code is, it is whitelisting urls like

`school.stealpassword.com`

`school.xxx`

Comment: Maybe this can help https://regex101.com/r/mP4nB8/1
When you're whitelisting like this, I would say it is beneficial to be more specific than just checking if it contains some word :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a whitelist for the domains you want to allow, then use the built-in `parse_url` php function to extract the domain from the url and check against the whitelist.

```
$testLinks = [
    'https://school.com',
    'https://www.school.com',
    'http://school.com',
    'http://wwwschool.com',
    'school.com',
    'www.school.com',
    'www.schoool.com',
    'https://www.schoool.com',
    'www.schoool.com',
    'http://www.schoool.com',
    'schoool.com'
];

$whitelistDomains = [
    'school.com'
];

foreach($testLinks as $link){
    print $link . ' is ' . (checkUrl($link,$whitelistDomains)===TRUE? 'valid':'spam'). PHP_EOL;
}


function checkUrl($link,$whitelistDomains)
{

    $urlData = parse_url($link);

    $domain = isset($urlData['host'])? $urlData['host'] : $link;

    if (in_array($domain,$whitelistDomains)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }   

}
```

Will output

```
https://school.com is valid
https://www.school.com is spam
http://school.com is valid
http://wwwschool.com is spam
school.com is valid
www.school.com is spam
www.schoool.com is spam
https://www.schoool.com is spam
www.schoool.com is spam
http://www.schoool.com is spam
schoool.com is spam
```

Adding `www.school.com` and `wwwschool.com` to the whitelist will output the following

```
https://school.com is valid
https://www.school.com is valid  // this becomes valid
http://school.com is valid
http://wwwschool.com is valid // this becomes valid
school.com is valid
www.school.com is valid
www.schoool.com is spam
https://www.schoool.com is spam
www.schoool.com is spam
http://www.schoool.com is spam
schoool.com is spam
```

Comment: easy to implement and easy to understand :) thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
preg_match("/(([h|H]ttps?:\/\/)?[w|W]ww)?\.?([s|S]chool\.com.*)/", $input, $output);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fAU

Comment: And let all letters be uppercase - just lowercase before matching to make it simpler.

Comment: @LubosHoracek good idea. Something to remember till next time.

Answer (score 0):

All whitelisted URLs have "school.com" in common. So add this whole string to your regexp.